# Draw a float number from a file into a variable in C

Tags: file, draw

Let's say that i have a txt file like this:

```
12.00 14.15
```

and so on. The point is that the float numbers are separated by a space (or whatever).
I want to read the first number and assign it to a float variable to be able to use it. How can i do this? with casting?

I need a sample in C. Thanks for the help

Comment: @zelldon yes and it didn't work. Instead of mislead the focus of the problem to my previous mistakes i asked directly for the simple solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to read a double (no need to use float, double is the same and gives better precision) from `a.txt` use the following:

```
double d;
FILE* fp = fopen("a.txt", "r");
if (fscanf(fp, "%lf", &d) == 1)
{
  // do something with 'd'
}
else
{
  // reading a number failed
}
```

Comment: I am absolutely not a fan of writing someone else's code for them. But it's just the "skeleton", he probably needs to add more logic in his code to accomplish whatever task he wants to.

Comment: @JacekCz what do you need the line of code for? If i would have wrote something, would have been only something wrong or misleading. I only needed a "skeleton", like neoaggelos said, for a more complex problem, and it worked. So thanks for the answer!